# Add tomee.xml resource with constructor parameters

Tags: jndi, openejb, apache-tomee

Trying to add a "[java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)" resource in tomee.xml, but the parameters are not being passed to the constructor. Here is the addition to the tomee.xml:

```
    <Resource id="someJndiName" class-name="java.net.URL" factory-name="URL" constructor="spec">
      spec http://google.com
    </Resource>
```

This causes:

```
    INFO: Creating Resource(id=someJndiName)
    Dec 18, 2013 5:10:12 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OpenEJBErrorHandler handleUnknownError
    SEVERE: FATAL ERROR: Unknown error in Assembler.  Please send the following stack trace and this message to users@openejb.apache.org :
     java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ReflectionUtil.toParameterList(ReflectionUtil.java:1026)
       at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ReflectionUtil.findStaticFactory(ReflectionUtil.java:811)
       at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ObjectRecipe.findFactory(ObjectRecipe.java:538)
       at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ObjectRecipe.internalCreate(ObjectRecipe.java:274)
       at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:96)
```

Based on [OpenEJB/TomEE Resources: how does it work?](http://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/openejbtomee-resources-how-does-it-work/) the code is using reflection to call the constructor and should be passing the parameter, but this does not appear to be the case here. Is this a bug, or is there another way to pass parameters to the constructor?

I tried adding an entry in "%TomEE%/conf/system.properties", but it made no change.

```
    someJndiName.spec=http://google.com
```

I tried using the 3 parameter constructor for URL, with the same result.

```
    <Resource id="someJndiName" class-name="java.net.URL" factory-name="URL" constructor="protocol, host, file">
      protocol http
      host google.com
      file 
    </Resource>
```

My current need is to add "java.net.URL" objects to the server resources, but being able to add arbitrary objects using this general method would be very useful.

Does some handler class need to be created for "java.net.URL" to be processed as a TomEE resource?

Answer (score 0):

are you still having this issue? This is working in TomEE 7.1.0.

`resources.xml`:

```xml
<resources>
    <Resource id="myURL"
              class-name="java.net.URL"
              constructor="spec">
        spec http://google.com
    </Resource>
</resources>
```

`Application.java`:

```java
package com.test.application;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import java.net.URL;

@Slf4j
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class Application {

    @Resource(name = "myURL")
    private URL url;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        log.info("URL={}", url);
    }
}
```